# Extract Part of String using cut/awk or anything

Tags: linux, shell

```
[DOSLB] : [dmob7h-002.on.bell.ca] : [61421820100992016102414274381420414330] : [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] : [ca.bell.tv.doslb.infrastructure.logging.LoggingAspect] : [Ending execution of the class: ca.bell.tv.doslb.application.webservice.impl.RetrieveLocalSubscriberDelegateImpl] : [Method: getRetrieveLocalSubscriber[Call ended at: 2016-10-24 14:27:44.150] : [lasted 0 sec, 305 ms] : [WITHINLIMITS]]
```

I wanted to extract **getRetrieveLocalSubscriber** from the above string. But I can not be specific with its position and also the string since it is a service name so it will change by time in the log and the position may change but it will be in the same format,  **[Method: getRetrieveLocalSubscriber[Call ended at: 2016-10-24 14:27:44.150]** this portion will always be the same.

and I also wanted to extract the **lasted 0 sec** part but the problem is the seconds will always change.

I want the output like **getRetrieveLocalSubscriber** in one variable and
**lasted 0 sec** in another variable

I have tried awk command 
    `cat out_log.txt | awk -F '[:]' '{print $11}'` 
which is giving output is **getRetrieveLocalSubscriber[Call ended at**

Comment: What do you want from the `getRetrieveLocalSubscriber` just the string or the metrics `[Call ended at: 2016-10-24 14:27:44.150]` ?

Comment: please edit your Q to include required Output AND what you have tried already. S.O. isn't a free code writing service ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I have edited my requirement now you can answer this. By the way thanks for the suggestion  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
echo "[DOSLB] : [dmob7h-002.on.bell.ca] : [61421820100992016102414274381420414330] : [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] : [ca.bell.tv.doslb.infrastructure.logging.LoggingAspect] : [Ending execution of the class: ca.bell.tv.doslb.application.webservice.impl.RetrieveLocalSubscriberDelegateImpl] : [Method: getRetrieveLocalSubscriber[Call ended at: 2016-10-24 14:27:44.150] : [lasted 0 sec, 305 ms] : [WITHINLIMITS]]" | perl -ne '/Method: getRetrieveLocalSubscriber\[Call ended at: (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d+?)\] : \[lasted (\d+?) sec, (\d+?) ms\]/ && print "Call end: $1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7, lasted for $8s $9ms";'
Call end: 2016-10-24 14:27:44.150, lasted for 0s 305ms
```

Or, if such strings are in a file:

```
cat test.log | perl -ne '/Method: getRetrieveLocalSubscriber\[Call ended at: (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d+?)\] : \[lasted (\d+?) sec, (\d+?) ms\]/ && print "Call end: $1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6.$7, lasted for $8s $9ms";'
```

This regular expression also accepts different "call end" time. You can replace

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d+?)
```

part in this regexp with **2016-10-24 14:27:44.150** and **$8** and **$9** with **$1** and **$2** respectively to match only strings with

```
Call ended at: 2016-10-24 14:27:44.150
```

substrings.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this;

```
grep -o -P '(?=\[Method: getRetrieveLocalSubscriber).*(?<=ms])' yourFile
```

or

```
 grep -o -P '(?=\[Call).*(?<=ms])' yourFile
```

Eg;

```
user@host$ grep -o -P '(?=\[Method: getRetrieveLocalSubscriber).*(?<=ms])' test
[Method: getRetrieveLocalSubscriber[Call ended at: 2016-10-24 14:27:44.150] : [lasted 0 sec, 305 ms]

user@host$ grep -o -P '(?=\[Call).*(?<=ms])' test
[Call ended at: 2016-10-24 14:27:44.150] : [lasted 0 sec, 305 ms]
```